# Syntax for success code of "Where" command

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

What is the syntax to get a success code when running the "Where" command? I need that to end a loop.

And what is the syntax to get the directory of the found file?

This command:

WHERE /r "C:\Dir\Dir2  FindMe.txt"

correctly shows the file in the command window:

C:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\FindMe.txt

But now what do I do?
Please be kind, I am less than a novice.

EDIT:
My question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562506, but in my case the file I am looking for is not in the direct path but up, over, and then down. Taking the example given, and starting at the same directory, my file could be in C:\Temp\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3**\Dir14\Dir15**\FindMe.txt. Meaning I need to go up to Dir3, there find my file with the WHERE command and stop my loop.

EDIT 2: I stripped everything off I could. Make a txt file "FindMe.txt" somewhere, put this code snipped as a .cmd someplace else and then drag another .txt file onto the .cmd file. With any luck it should stop with the directory of FindMe.txt as answer. What I need help with is the pseudo code:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET "cmdPath=%~dp0"
SET "cmdPath=%cmdPath:~0,-1%"  ::without back slash
SET "searchPath=%cmdPath%"     ::start search here

:loop
  IF EXIST "%searchPath%\FindMe.txt" (
    set "txtPath=%searchPath%
    ECHO txtPath%searchPath%\FindMe.txt
    GOTO :EOF
  )
  IF "%searchPath:~1%" == ":" (
    ECHO FindMe.txt not found.
    pause
    GOTO :EOF
  )
  echo searchPath=%searchPath%
rem run: WHERE /r "%searchPath%" /q FindMe.txt
rem if successful (found) (
rem run: WHERE /r "%searchPath%" FindMe.txt 
rem just keep the path and rename to txtPath
rem goto :eof
  CALL :getPath "%searchPath%"
  GOTO loop
:end

:getPath
SET "searchPath=%~dp1"
SET "searchPath=%searchPath:~0,-1%"
:end
:eof
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your question is too vague. What do you mean "success code"? It would be helpful if you share with us what you are trying to do. Also if you  add the portion of the batch code that is giving you problems to your question, we can see the entire context. There is an [edit] link under the question.

Comment: @CharlieRB see my edit

Answer (score 1):

To find out whether the where command was succesful, investigate the %errorlevel% after running:

```
c:\tmp>where x
c:\tmp\x
c:\tmp>echo %errorlevel%
0
c:\tmp>where y
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
c:\tmp>echo %errorlevel%
1
```

And to store the output of the find command, you can use (but there are multiple ways):

```
c:\tmp>for /f %i in ('where cmd.exe') do @set ans=%i

c:\tmp>echo %ans%
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

(You could also pipe the output to a temp file and then read the temp file, for instance.)

Note that if you put this into a batch file, you will need to double the %-signs in the line with the for-command.

Also note that if you would do this multiple times, say in a subroutine, the 'ans' does not get set if there is no file found (because the for loop did not have any iterations - if this doesn't make sense to you just ignore it), so you need to check the errorlevel before you use the ans.

Also note that checking the errorlevel after the for loop will not tell you anything about the where command itself.

Don't ask why you can't just do something like **path=`where x`;**, because I don't know. And batch scripting always gives me a headache. There are much more powerful scripting languages available, by the way, if you want to get ahead in scripting.

Here's a way that doesn't use the errorlevel at all. Put the code below in a batchfile and change the where command to the file that you are looking for. Leave the "2> nul" part intact though, or it will keep spitting error messages that the file wasn't found until the file was found.

```
@echo off

REM set location to an empty string
set location=

REM set the command to run in a loop
set command="where testfile 2> nul"

REM simulating a while loop
:while1
REM running the command defined above and storing the result in the "location" variable.
REM Note: result will only be stored if a file was actually found. If not, the "set location" part is not executed.
for /f %%i in ('%command%') do @set location=%%i
if "%location%" == "" (
    REM location is STILL an empty string like we set in the beginning; no file found
    REM let's sleep for a second to not overload the system
    timeout /t 1 > nul
    REM ... and go back the :while tag
    goto :while1
)

REM If we got to this point, a file was found, because location wasn't an empty string any more.

echo location: %location%
```

Comment: Thank you, but this I have to digest. The success code I understand, I think, but haven't tried yet. I was prepared to run WHERE twice, once to stop the loop and once to get the directory. Maybe I can use something similar to the success code?

Comment: How about something like this? I found a way around having to execute the where command twice after the file has been found, just don't test the errorlevel at all but the assigned value. Don't know why I didn't think of that before. See my updated answer.

Comment: I tried your (first) suggestion but could not get it to work. Have a look at my last edit, maybe that explains my problem better. - Thanks for hanging in there with me. I have spent countless hours over days with this but did not get anywhere.

Comment: Took longer than expected, see updated answer now.